# Why is $\displaystyle \sum_{y} P(X=x,Y=y) = P(X=x)$?

Tags: probability, expectation

[image]

Why is $\displaystyle \sum_{y}P(X= x, Y = y) = P(X =x)$

I do not seem to be able to understand this. Its on the 3rd line of the image

Comment: That isn't remotely the claim made on the 3rd line of the image.

Comment: The actual claim is $\displaystyle \sum_{y} P(X=x,Y=y) = P(X=x)$ and $\displaystyle \sum_x P(X=x,Y=y) = P(Y=y)$.

Comment: Also, there's a huge difference between $X$ and $x$ and between $Y$ and $y$.

Comment: X is a random variable and x is a value?

Comment: That is precisely the case.

Comment: But I still do not understand the claim

Comment: Do you understand the symbol $\displaystyle \sum$?

Comment: Yes. It's a summation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is $\displaystyle \sum_{y} P(X=x,Y=y) = P(X=x)$?

Proof:

Consider the sets $\{X=x,Y=y\}$. Note that $$\bigcup_{y}\{X=x,Y=y\}=\{X=x\}$$

And $\{X=x,Y=y\}$ are disjoint.

Hence $P(\bigcup_{y}\{X=x,Y=y\})= \sum_{y} P(X=x,Y=y) = P(X=x)$

Comment: Why are the random variables disjoint

Comment: Are you saying that since we have covered all the cases of y, Hence y is not a factor in the joint pdf

Comment: You may do that by yourself: start with Let $y_1\neq y_2$, then $\{X=x,Y=y_1\}\cap\{X=x,Y=y_2\}=\emptyset$

Comment: Ah i see now. Thanks a lot

Comment: read about total probability, I guess for your second comment.